# Duplicate Relationships in Rails/MySQL Healthcare Application

Tags: mysql, sql, ruby-on-rails

**Overview of the Application**

I am building a Ruby on Rails application to organize medications, using MySQL. The goal of this application is to provide dosage specific treatment recommendations, and also provide more general information about the utility of drugs to treat various conditions.

**Current Entities**

“Drug” - Example: “Abilify”

“Dosage” - Example: “10mg”

“Condition" - Example: “Depression”

**Potential Entities For Required Use Cases**

“Prescription” (Therapy + Condition) => This is required for dosage specific data, for a specific condition. Clinical research may be attached to this entity.

“Therapy" (Drug + Dosage) => This is required because it represents how most medications are priced, and how most medications are interchanged between 3rd party health applications, using a government standards primary key known as a RxNorm Concept Unique Identifier.

“Usage” (Drug + Condition) => This is required for connecting drugs to conditions, without consideration to dosage. Some drugs are used to treat many conditions.

**Concern**

These three models, if implemented, create duplicate relationships between either drug and condition, or drug and dosage. How can we build out a normalized system that supports our needs for both dosage and condition specific tools, as well as dosage and condition agnostic tools?

**Example**

“Abilify 5 mg for depression“ => The “Prescription” entity would allow us to attach clinical studies, and alternatives, for 5 mg of Abilify in the treatment of depression. The “Therapy” entity would allow us to find pricing, as well as 3rd party supplemental data, for 5 mg of Abilify. The “Usage” entity would allow us to track all conditions that Abilify is used to treat, along with their efficacy in treating these various conditions.

Comment: `Therapy` looks like a listing of drug packaging, for instance we may get "Abilify" in 250mg boxes, is that what it tries to represent?

Comment: Note that `Usage` can be easily extracted from `Prescription`. Conversely, if `Usage` represents an exhaustive list of possible drug uses, you could just use a foreign key in `Prescription` on this table.

Comment: @didierc yes, therapy could be viewed that way. And yes, I thought having a usages foreign key in the Prescription table would be a good approach. But still doesn't not resolve the duplicate relationship between drug and dosage. It would exist once in the prescription entity and once in the therapy entity.

Comment: I think you should pick a db design tool, and try to build a first model. If you get end up with duplication somewhere (ie, more than one column found on several tables), extract that duplication to another table and replace by foreign keys. If you get stuck, post your table defs here and we'll see how this can be worked out.